# Android Restart a Service

Tags: android, service

I have the following question:

I start my activity and i call bindService in order to start a service which in background downloads data from an API.
When it finish, it calls stopSelf().

But if i want to call again bindService in my Activity in order to download other data, nothing happens.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a one off download that you're doing, wouldn't using AsyncTask be more appropriate?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: It depends on how big the download is. AsyncTask works only if the activity stays in foreground. For a long running offline data synchronization a service is more appropriate.